# Reputation points earned by wiki tag edits are removed after a while. Why?

Tags: discussion, reputation, tag-wiki

This is the third or fourth time it happens:
Reputation points earned by wiki tag edits are removed after a while. Why?

Does it make sense to see my rep grow and then drain?

Comment: Perhaps the tag you created the wiki for was removed?

Comment: No... I see that some still are there.

Comment: Could you link to those for which you've lost rep?

Comment: This, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app. Anyway, it doesn't matter. I'll live with that.

Comment: Are you sure you lost reputation? Can't it be that you simply don't get reputation any more because you've passed the maximum of 1000rep for suggested edits?

Comment: That's an essentially useless tag. Don't waste your time on that sort of tag, it's gonner.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that limit. But I think I'm still far under it. And if so, I shouldn't see the rep growing (it was 8354 before posting this question) and then draining...

Comment: In your reputation history, do you have "show removed posts" enabled at the very bottom of that list?

Comment: I thought I had to edit every possible tag - Including marking the wrong or misspelled ones as such.

Comment: Nope, just focus on the good ones.

Comment: @BobMalooga You can see how much rep you've earned from suggested edits at the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: OK, I'll keep your advices in mind. Thank you for your time!

Comment: The tag [tag:app] has been removed from all questions it was on.

Comment: I see, thank you. I'm still relatively new (< 1 year) to SO, and not all the mechanisms are clear to me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it **lacks sufficient understanding** of the SO politics.

Comment: No need to close your own question, Meta is here to help you understand how SO works (amongst other things).

Comment: I was trying to make some fun of my error ;) self-kidding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suggested edits give you 2 rep per accepted edit, but only up to a maximum of 1000 rep, as explained in [How Does Reputation Work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Given a total of [657 suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2649012/bob-malooga?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), I would be surprised if you haven't hit 500 accepted suggestions. In fact, a quick check learns you have  had 607 accepted. So you probably haven't lost reputation, you simply aren't getting any at this point in time.

Comment: Oh, I see. My fault I thought I could give 1000 accepted suggestions.

Comment: Nope, as per the linked post *"you suggest an edit and it is accepted: +2 (up to a total of +1000 per user)"* ... so 2 rep per accepted edit and 1000 max.